# How to avoid calling bringToFront() in onDraw of custom view?

Tags: android

I have a custom view as you can see in `activity_main.xml`. Right now it is hidden under the camera fragment. I want it to show up on top of it.

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
<com.snappiesticker.cwac4.StickerView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </FrameLayout>
```

This is the class itself:

```
public class StickerView extends View {

    Bitmap bitmap;

    float x = 2;
    float y = 2;

    public StickerView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context,attrs);
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.paunch);
    }


    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, x, y, null);
        // I wanted to put it here but that would cause the loop described below.  
    }


}
```

by loop, I mean: `onDraw` is called, which calls `bringToFront`, which asks the layout to be re-rendered. which calls `onDraw`, which calls `bringToFront`, etc. etc.

This is what I want to avoid.

This is instantiated in the `mainActivity`.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements CameraHostProvider {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        DemoCameraFragment current = new DemoCameraFragment();

        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.fragment_container, current)
                .commit();
        // can I somehow tell it to render the custom sticker view at the front here?
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did I understand correctly, you want to have your custom **StickerView** to remain on top of camera fragment? If that is the case you could simply refine your layout to something like this too ;

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <com.snappiesticker.cwac4.StickerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Using this layout your camera fragment is added below **StickerView** and there's no need to call *bringToFront()* at all. If you use your root layout as fragment container the fragment is added after your custom view i.e above it.